# INSERT OR REPLACE multiple rows, but there is no unique or primary keys

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, rdbms

Hi I'm running into the following problem on SQlite3

I have a simple table

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (id INT, cnt INT);
```

There are some rows already in the table.

I have some data I want to be inserted into the table: {(id0, cnt0), (id1, cnt1)...}

I want to insert data into the table, on id conflict, update TestTable.cnt = TestTable.cnt + value.cnt

(values.cnt is cnt0, cnt1 ... basically my data to be inserted)

*** But the problem is, there is no primary or unique constraint on id, and I am not allowed to change it!

What I currently have :

In my program I loop through all the values

```
UPDATE TestTABLE SET count = count + value.cnt WHERE id = value.id;

if (sqlite3_changes() == 0)

INSERT INTO MyTable (id, cnt) values (value.id, value.cnt);
```

But the problem is, with a very large dataset, doing 2 queries for each data entry takes too long. I'm trying to bundle multiple entries together into one call.

Please let me know if you have questions about my description, thank you for helping!

Comment: Create a temporary unique index on the column.

Comment: Please elaborate on "not allowed to change it", because that certainly limits possible solutions to optimize the process.  Are you not allowed to execute any DDL statements?  Are you allowed to create formal temporary tables (with the TEMPORARY keyword)?  Because sqlite does not have "temporary indexes", Shawn's suggestion would require actually adding, then later removing, an index... would that contradict your limitations?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to create temporary tables, then do the following.  Although I don't show it here, I suggest wrapping all this in a transaction.  This technique will likely increase efficiency even if you are also able to add a temporary unique index.  (In that case you could use an [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) with source data in the temporary table.)

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE data(id INT, cnt INT);
```

Now insert the new data into the temporary table, whether by using the host-language data libraries or crafting an insert statement similar to

```sql
INSERT INTO data (id, cnt)
VALUES (1, 100),
       (2, 200),
       (5, 400),
       (7, 500);
```

Now update all existing rows using the single UPDATE statement.  SQLite does not have a convenient syntax for joining tables and/or providing a source query for an UPDATE statement.  However, one can use nested statement to provide similar convenience:

```sql
UPDATE TestTable AS tt
SET cnt = cnt + ifnull((SELECT cnt FROM data WHERE data.id == tt.id), 0)
WHERE tt.id IN (SELECT id FROM data);
```

Note that the two nested queries are independent of each other.  In fact, one could eliminate the WHERE clause altogether and get the same results for this simple case.  The WHERE clause is simply to make it more efficient, only attempting to update matching id's.  The other subquery in the SET clause also specifies a match on `id`, but alone it would still allow updates of rows that don't have a match, defaulting to a `null` value and being converted to 0 (by `isnull()` function) for a no-op.  By the way, without the `isnull()` function, the sum would result in null and would overwrite non-null values.

Finally, insert only rows with non-existing `id` values:

```sql
INSERT INTO TestTable (id, cnt)
SELECT data.id, data.cnt
FROM data LEFT JOIN TestTable
     ON data.id == TestTable.id
WHERE TestTable.id IS NULL;
```